# Send Magento order confirmation after succesful checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, email

Here's my problem: When a customer in my Magento store places an order, the confirmation mail is being sent right away. Even when the payment procedure is not done.

I want the order confirmation mail only to be sent when the payment is done. For example when someone chooses PayPal and clicks on Place Order button, the person is redirected to PayPal, makes the payment: confirmation mail send. But when the person is cancelling the payment in PayPal, nothing should be sent.

Next to that I still need blind copy or separate order confirmation mail to ourselves.

I did not find a solution on Google or Stackoverflow, so I hope someone can help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, actually very simple: in the settings of my payment provider I could select the option the send a new order mail after succesful checkout. I'm using the Dutch payment provider Sisow.